# Alarm ringtone plays after calling

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, custom-roms, miui

This problem started 2-3 months ago. It doesn't matter who initiates call, after disconnect my phone plays the standard melody used to wake me up in the morning (Dreamland). I don't know how to turn it off, because no process is shown in task manager. Last time I did it by holding HOME key for 1 second, sometimes I just reboot the phone.

I wanna disable it since it's very annoying and causes downside effects to my work. Did anybody face such thing? How can I investigate the incident further?

As I thought (and following advice given down), when I changed alarm melody to another one, melody played after call was changed to the new melody. This time I stopped it using memory cleaner.

**DETAILS:**
Phone model: *Star X920 (HTC Butterfly)*
Firmware: *MIUI 4.4.25*
Android: *4.2.1 JOP40D*
Kernel: *3.4.5*

Comment: If this is occurring at all times then it might be a bug or something.

Comment: Have you tried, as an experiment, to change you morning alarm ring tone to something else just to see if the same ringtone plays after a call. If not than it is not related to your alarms and may help you narrow it down.

Comment: @MANI of coarse it's bug. I need a workaround.

Comment: @Lazer I changed alarm ringtone and phantom melody also was changed.

Comment: @Danatela Does this only happen if you have alarms set or does this happen even with no alarms set? Have you tried deleting all your alarms? If this works maybe try adding them back one by one. Please keep us updated.

Comment: @Lazer it seems your advice helped :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments:

Have you tried, as an experiment, to change you morning alarm ring tone to something else just to see if the same ringtone plays after a call. If not than it is not related to your alarms and may help you narrow it down.

Does this only happen if you have alarms set or does this happen even with no alarms set? Have you tried deleting all your alarms? If this works maybe try adding them back one by one. Please keep us updated.

Comment: OK, I turned alarm off and sound was gone. Normal beep returned.